# Bootstrap UL with bullets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need a ul with bullets with bootstrap loaded on the page.  I cannot find a single example of how to do this with bootstrap on the page (google only results in examples to REMOVE bullets, not show bullets).  Is there a class I should be adding that is undocumented?

I have tried adding

```
ul {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

does absolutely nothing: https://jsfiddle.net/49kwo5pL/2/

The documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#unordered) says you have to add a class to remove the bullets, but that doesn't see to be the actual case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `ul` has `padding` and `margin` which Bootstrap removes in its CSS.

So try adding it.

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');


ul {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
    padding-left:1em !important;
    margin-left:1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Why</li>
    <li>are</li>
    <li>there</li>
    <li>no</li>
    <li>bullets?!?!?!!?!?!?</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

The left padding is also removed by Bootstrap. Add it back to reveal the bullets.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/49kwo5pL/3/

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer didn't work for me, however after small tweak I manged to get it work. May be this will help someone. Thanks.

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 1em !important;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

li {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to show the bullet points is changing the bootstrap `display: block` for the list-item class to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert): `display: revert`. That's all!

Then I just added padding/margin as other answers suggested.